Error creating bean with name 'catalogDaoService', Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0
Error message:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6da648c5 testClass = ru.sbrf.llt.autotests.testing.service.T5196Test, locations = [], classes = [ru.sbrf.llt.autotest.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@63e5b8aa, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@3f6cce7f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2407a36c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@44dfdd58, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@f590c3b4], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogDaoService' defined in file [C:\Work\catalog-autotest-new\target\classes\ru\sbrf\llt\autotest\service\dao\CatalogDaoService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cardRepository' defined in ru.sbrf.llt.autotest.service.repository.CardRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository$AjcClosure79
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cardRepository' defined in ru.sbrf.llt.autotest.service.repository.CardRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository$AjcClosure79
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository$AjcClosure79
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2555)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ReflectionUtils.findConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:536)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository$AjcClosure79
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 124 more

My CatalogDaoService.java:
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CatalogDaoService {

    private final CardRepository cardRepository;
}

CardRepository.java
@Repository
public interface CardRepository extends JpaRepository<Card, Long>{


    @Query("select card from Card card where card.dpan in (:pans)")
    List<Card> getCardsByPans(List<String> pans);
}

Card.java

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARD")
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@DynamicInsert
public class Card extends AbstractCard {

  
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "s_card")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "s_card",
            sequenceName = "s_card",
            allocationSize = 100
    )
    private Long id;

 
    @Column(name = "id_card_line", updatable = false)
    private Long idCardLine;

 
    @Column(name = "event_time")
    private ZonedDateTime eventTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<CardToken> tokenInfoList = new HashSet<>();
}


Also I made configuration class for JPA:

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "ru.sbrf.llt.autotest.service.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "catalogEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "catalogTransactionManager"
)
public class CatalogStorageConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.hbm2ddl}")
    private String hbm2ddl;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource catalogDatasourceProp() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "catalogTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate catalogJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("catalogDatasourceProp") DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean catalogEntityManager(
            @Qualifier("catalogDatasourceProp") DataSource dataSource
    ) throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("ru.sbrf.llt.autotest.service.repository");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", dataSource.getConnection().getSchema());
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager catalogTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("catalogEntityManager") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean managerFactoryBean
    ) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(managerFactoryBean.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}

And when I run my Test class, I face with the error above
public class T5196Test extends TestBase {

    @Test
    void testAcceptEvents() throws Exception {
        String jsonString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("src/test/resources/files/T5196.json")));
        Empty response = sendEvent(jsonString);
        Assertions.assertEquals(Empty.getDefaultInstance(), response);

        long count = catalogDaoService.getCardRepository().count();
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, count);

    }
}

Help, please!
The UnsatisfiedDependencyException error indicates that Spring cannot create the CatalogDaoService bean because it cannot create the CardRepository bean. This can be caused by several issues, including incorrect Spring Data JPA configuration or missing dependencies. I checked all my classes and still dont get it.
UPD: added pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </parent>
  
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <log4.version>2.20.0</log4.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.19</aspectj.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
     
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>openshift-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <version>0.8.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>
                        com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.17.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                            <value>true</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportDirectory>target/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                    <reportingOutputDirectory>target/site</reportingOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

</project>


prolly missing @autowired on @requiredargctor(onConstructor_=@autowired)

Could you show us your pom.xml file, at least part with dependencies?

Show your build file. The fact thatyou have a ClassNotFoundException looks like your dependencies are a mess. I also wonder why did you create a configuration for JPA, do you have multiple datasources and/or entitymanagers? If not you don't need it and you are only making things extra complex.

@IvanVasiljevic and M.Deinum, added pom.xml

You must use Maven to run your test.
mvn -Dtest=ru.sbrf.llt.autotests.testing.service.T5196Test test

If this does not help, try cleaning and recompiling.
mvn clean install

